# Making new arrays in each iteration of a foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm very new to this so I could be going in completely the wrong direction.

I'm using a web crawler library I want to return an array of results for each page I scrape. My problem isn't with the scraper though.

I have start with an indexed array $links whose values are the urls I want to scrape for information.
if I go:

```
foreach ($links as $key=>$value) {
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', $value);
    $crawler->filter('p.scores')->each(function ($node) {
        $thisscore = $node->text();
        print $thisscore;
        });
};
```

it prints out all the results on the screen but I want the results to be in a different array for each of the foreach loops i.e. end up with @results0 @results1 @results2

Comment: Just take it in an array variable `$results[]=$thisscore;`.

Comment: What does that do? I need to have separate arrays for each entry in the $links array. I'm still confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create an array and populate it at each iteration

```
$new_array = array();
foreach ($links as $key=>$value) {
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', $value);
    $crawler->filter('p.scores')->each(function ($node) {
        $thisscore = $node->text();
       // print $thisscore;
        $new_array[] = $thisscore;
    });
};
```

Now you have all results in your `$new_array`

Comment: Variables are not global by default in PHP. For closures, you should use the `use` keyword.

Comment: Thank you but doesn't that put all my results into one array whereas I want separate arrays for each of the $links

Comment: Try to put this `$new_array[][] = $thisscore;` so you will have one sub array each iteration

Comment: That's empty when I print_r it outside the foreach. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You are populating the array in the loop so you are abke to print_r($new_array); outside the loop

Comment: How can I reference them later or pass them out the loop?